# How to make state of window idle until button is pressed in python tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have a window with start button and set of some widgets in different frames.Now i want to make the window idle(disabled state) until the "start" button is clicked.Help me to resolve this issue.My code is as below

```
from tkinter import *



class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self,  master):
    super(Application,self).__init__(master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

  def create_widgets(self):
    self.be=Button(self,text="start")
    self.be.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="s")

    self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
    self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
    self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
    self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

    self.rowconfigure(0, pad=5)
    self.rowconfigure(1, pad=5)
    self.f3=Frame(self)
    self.f3.grid(row=2,column=1)
    fuel = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    fuel.grid(row=1, column=0)
    Temp = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    Temp.grid(row=1, column=1)
    Th = Button(self.f3,text="Button",width=19)
    Th.grid(row=1, column=2)    
    Eo = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    Eo.grid(row=1, column=3)

    Bh = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    Bh.grid(row=2, column=0)        
    Abs = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    Abs.grid(row=2, column=1)         
    sp = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    sp.grid(row=2, column=2) 
    fo = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
    fo.grid(row=2, column=3) 

root= Tk()
app=Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rather need to loop over the widgets and disable them one by one because you can not disable an entire `Frame` object just like that.

So you will need to use [`winfo_children()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) to probe the child widgets.

Then you will need to append a method to `self.be` button using the [`command`](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) callback to enable the child widgets back again.

## Full program

Here is the program you are looking for:

```
'''
Created on Apr 29, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

   def __init__(self,  master):
       super(Application,self).__init__(master)
       self.grid()
       self.create_widgets()

   def create_widgets(self):
       self.be=Button(self,text="start", command = self.enable_widgets)
       self.be.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="s")

       self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
       self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
       self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
       self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

       self.rowconfigure(0, pad=5)
       self.rowconfigure(1, pad=5)
       self.f3=Frame(self)
       self.f3.grid(row=2,column=1)
       fuel = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       fuel.grid(row=1, column=0)
       Temp = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       Temp.grid(row=1, column=1)
       Th = Button(self.f3,text="Button",width=19)
       Th.grid(row=1, column=2)    
       Eo = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       Eo.grid(row=1, column=3)

       Bh = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       Bh.grid(row=2, column=0)        
       Abs = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       Abs.grid(row=2, column=1)         
       sp = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       sp.grid(row=2, column=2) 
       fo = Button(self.f3, text="Button",width=19)
       fo.grid(row=2, column=3) 
       for child in self.f3.winfo_children():
           child.configure(state = 'disable')


   def enable_widgets(self):
       '''Enable the child widgets'''
       for child in self.f3.winfo_children():
           child.configure(state = 'normal')


root= Tk()
app=Application(root)
app.mainloop()
```

## Demo

At the start of the program, the GUI will look like this:

[image]

After clicking on the `Start` button:

[image]

Comment: I have one more query.In the above program each button performs separate functions.On clicking button new window will open which is a child class.Now i want to perform functionalities of each button simultaneously.for example if i click button1, it should keep on accepting input from file and giving output even if i click button2.Can i use thread concept here?If yes can u show me how?

Comment: It is useless to use threads for such thing. Just append those callback methods to the buttons using **command** option

Comment: I tried that but if i take two buttons both the function will not work simultaneously@Billal

Comment: but how can you click on 2 buttons simultaneously? that is impossible :)

Comment: thats true but for example if i click on button1 which collects the readings from some sensor and displays it on the gui and now if i click on button2 which does same thing.when i click on second button the results of button1 also should keep on displaying the result while the result of second button also should be displayed until both terminated by user.